# "InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error" error after updating a python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

After updating a package (IPython in my case) using `pip install -U ipython` running any Python script that uses entry points fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adrian/dev/indico/env/bin/indico", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  ...
  File "/home/adrian/dev/indico/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 94, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8], requirement_string))
pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'< 2.0'"
```

Nothing else changed, I did not update any other libraries.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is caused by an issue in `setuptools==20.2.1` which is pulled in by IPython (`setuptools>..`), so a `pip install -U` updated it.

Until a fixed version is released or the broken version is pulled from PyPI there is a simple workaround (but note that it will break again if something updates setuptools):

- `pip install -U pip`
- `pip uninstall setuptools`
- `pip install 'setuptools<20.2'`

The `pip` update is needed since older versions of `pip` will not work without `setuptools` being installed

---

See these IRC logs and BitBucket issue for details:

- http://chat-logs.dcpython.org/day/pypa/2016-02-25
- https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issues/502/packaging-164-does-not-allow-whitepace

Comment: The uninstall is failing an *Operation not permitted:..* error.

Answer (score 14):

Try downgrading your pip to `8.1.1`:

```
pip install pip==8.1.1
```

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had `package = "2.8.0"` in my Pipfile. Changing it to `package = "==2.8.0"` fixed this error for me.